# Unit testing - use real value or mock?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, nunit, phpunit

I have a unit test that asserts whether a particular model has a property or not and whether that property is not null.

So, something like the following:

```
public function testHasMySpecialProperty()
{
    $this->assertTrue($this->model->getMySpecialProperty());
}
```

my question is what should model be.  A mock, or a real instatition of the object.

The object in this case is a user of a system.  So in order to load properly i would require the user id etc.  But if i simply fake it then the test feels useless

Comment: Do the real one, it'll better show how the app handles real values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Use mocks to stub out behavior of complex objects or objects with external dependencies, when that object is not the subject of the test.

So, if you are testing the behavior of `model`, use the real thing.  If `model` is a data object, with no behavior and no attachment to external resources (ex, does not make database calls), then use the real thing.  If `model` has some additional behavior or dependencies, and it is *not* the target of the test, go ahead and mock it.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `mock` is not really testing the model. Just pass the real object and check for the property. After all, that is what you are testing.

Answer (score 1):

you don't use mocks to test the mocks. you use mocks to cut off part of your *real* system you want to test. checking if mock has a property is testing a mock. it gives you no further knowledge about your real system.